# Create directory list where each line in list consists of mp3 file name and mp3 duration

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mp3

I wish to produce a list from the directory of the mp3 file names in the directory and the playing duration of each file.

The below command produces a list of mp3 files in the directory

```
for name in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$name" 2>&1 |  grep -o -P "(?<=Input #0, mp3, from ').*(?=.mp3':)"  ; done;
```

The below command produces a list of the duration of each of the MP3 files

```
for name in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$name" 2>&1 | grep -o -P '(?<=Duration: 00:).*(?=.[0-9]{2}, start)'  ; done;
```

I need to combine the output of both these commands into one output showing

- mm:ss filename
- mm:ss filename
- mm:ss filename
- mm:ss filename
- mm:ss filename
- mm:ss filename
- ..

Comment: You could combine your two commands with [`paste`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html#paste-invocation) and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time 0 idea. Something like this...(taking your code).

```
for name in *.mp3; 
do 
  a=$(ffmpeg -i "$name" 2>&1|grep -o -P "(?<=Input #0, mp3, from').*)(?=.mp3':)"
  b=$(ffmpeg -i "$name" 2>&1|grep -o -P '(?<=Duration: 00:).*(?=.[0-9]{2}, start)')
  echo "$b $a"
done;
```

Feel you free to use `printf` instead of `echo` and a formatted output.